# How do I check dataframe column value in list of strings?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` and want to create a new dataframe `df_b` from it but only taking the rows where the value of the row's column `df['id']` is in my list array `list_of_ids`.

Both `df['id']` and `list_of_ids` contain string values.

I thought of using a regex, but the regex would be huge since the length of `list_of_ids` is > 20 elements, so would need a generator over `list_of_ids` but I don't know how to apply that.

I was thinking something like:

```
list_of_ids = ["thing1", "thing2", "thing3" ]
df_b = df[df["id"].apply(lambda x: x in list_of_ids)==True]
```

Or I could use the `.str.contains()` method but pass a string that is built from all the elements of `list_of_ids` where they are separated by a pipe '|', but doing that doesn't seem "clean".

Comment: `df[df['id'].str.isin(list_of_ids)]`

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks. I'll accept this as an answer since you got there before @perl with it, otherwise I'll accept Perl's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating a sample DataFrame:

```
n = 50
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': list(string.ascii_letters[:n]),
    'n': range(n)})
df.head()

Out:
    id  n
0   a   0
1   b   1
2   c   2
3   d   3
4   e   4
```

Selecting values with ID matching values from the `ids` list:

```
ids = ['a', 'd', 'x', 'A']
df[df['id'].isin(ids)]

Out:
    id  n
0   a   0
3   d   3
23  x   23
26  A   26
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I needed.

Comment: @uncle-junky: if the answer solves your problem as an acceped solution, you might give an up-vote and also click the "solved-button" (just below th up-/down-voting buttons)

Comment: @pyano does it matter who got there first? I'm happy to give credit wherever depending on community rules/guidelines.

Comment: If @panktijk decides to post their solution as an answer you can decide to change to their answer as the accepted one after.  However if they do not wish to post it as answer and this one solves your problem, you should accept this one as the answer.